# Beamer Metropolis Theme - Adding Toc to Section Page

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, beamer-metropolis

Is there a way to add the Table of Contents to the Section page?
I know I can add the ToC seperatly before the section page, like in my MWE.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[sectionpage=progressbar]{metropolis}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
\setbeamerfont{currentsection in toc}{size=\Large}
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
\frame{\sectionpage}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{S1}
\begin{frame}
  Test
\end{frame}
\section{S2}
\section{S3}

\end{document}
```

[image: Section Page]
[image: ToC]

As result I want to add those gray Section Titles from the ToC to the Section Page. As an alternative I could change the style of the ToC (even though I dont know how) to match the section page style. It is not necessary to have this progress bar, even though I like it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5):

You can put the `\sectionpage` and the `\tableofcontents` in the same `\frame`, in the `\AtBeginSection` block:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\AtBeginSection{
  \frame{
    \sectionpage
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  }
}
\begin{document}

\section{S1}

\begin{frame}
  Test in section 1
\end{frame}

\section{S2}

\begin{frame}
  Test in section 2
\end{frame}

\section{S3}

\end{document}
```

[image: example of the code]